# Access data value from vue-hotel-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vue-hotel-datepicker](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker/) and after I select a date range I want to get that value, but I am not sure how. I tried several methods, but no good.

```
<HotelDatePicker
           @toggleDatepicker="getDate" // that's how I try to get the value, but is not workign
></HotelDatePicker>

  methods: {
    getDate(index) {
      console.log("i:", index); /I don't get here
    },
  }
```

Also I am not sure if `toggleDatepicker` is good, I didn't find in documentation how can I get that value. Also if I want to use a v-model to get that value, I get "true", "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of your plugin, you have to listen to [plugin events](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker/#events). So you can replace `@toggleDatepicker` by `@booking-clicked`.

***@*** if for event listening, so you have to check the event section of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `toggleDatePicker` isn't an event, but a method. You can try using the `check-in-changed` and `check-out-changed` events, or check out the other event options (however, I think these will fit your use case).